# Angular js get $valid value for elements in form tag seperated by div

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

I need to be able to get $valid value of the elements that are seperated by two div tags

here is a code pen with the set up .

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWVgyr?editors=101

```
<form name='form' ng-controller='A'>
    <div name='childForm1'>
      <input type='text' ng-model='tes' ng-required='true' />
    </div>

    <div name='childForm2'>
      <input type='text' ng-model='tes2' ng-required='true' />
    </div>

    <input type='button' ng-click='childForm1()' value='Child Form 1' />
    <input type='button' ng-click='childForm2()' value='Child Form 2' />

  </form>
```

So on click of Child Form 1 the $valid should return value validating only the elements in the div childForm1 similarlly if childForm2 is is selected then only elements under the div childForm2 should be validated.

Answer (score 1):

Use your input type for scope variable like this:

```
<div name='childForm1'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='data1.tes' ng-required='true' name="tes"/>
</div>

<div name='childForm2'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='data2.tes2' ng-required='true' name="tes2"/>
</div>
```

For controller use like this:

```
  var app=angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']);
  app.controller('A',function($scope){
  $scope.childForm1 = function(){
   alert($scope.form.tes.$valid);
 }

 $scope.childForm2 = function(){
   alert($scope.form.tes2.$valid);
   }
});
```

Comment: I need to find whether the elements under the div tag 'childForm1' are valid normally the syntax for validating elements that are directly under the form element is formName.$valid. I need specific elements under the form  to be validated.

Comment: Could you give me snap of your controller js.

Comment: Do not give  name attribute to DIV element.